# Scope Resolution problem in the ROS2 migration guide

Tags: ros, ros2, rclcpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While trying to migrate from ROS1 to ROS2 using the [migration guide](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Migration-Guide) there is a problem of scope declaration.

while compilation many of the classes of the `rclcpp` are said as not declared.

e.g. `auto node = rclcpp::node::Node::make_shared("talker");`, here rclcpp::node has not been declared.

Similarly in `rclcpp::rate::Rate loop_rate(10);`, here rclcpp::rate has not been declared.

I already have the `#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"` What else am i missing ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291639/scope-resolution-problem-in-the-ros2-migration-guide/) by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 667 on 2018-05-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) on 2018-05-18**:
It's possible that line in the guide is out of date. Does `rclcpp::Node::make_shared("talker")` work?

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-05-18**:
Yes, I also thought the same and changed it to `rclcpp::Node::make_shared("talker")`. This works. As i also saw in the `rclcpp::Node` class and there is no mention of `node`. I am just creating a node by using `auto node`. Also does that mean I should change `rclcpp::rate::Rate` `to rclcpp::Rate` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The extra namespaces `rclcpp::node` and `rclcpp::rate` were removed in this pull request https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/pull/416/files

Thanks for reporting it. I've updated the migration guide.

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2018-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-05-18**:
Thanks for the information :)